# How to route a Node.js Single Page App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, single-page-application

I'm trying to design a Single Page App using Node.js that has multiple tabs, and on each tab can contain a number of images or scripts, so I'd like to prevent loading the content of every tab each time a user visits the page. So ideally when a user switches tabs the server would send the html which contains the images and scripts and the client would display that without reloading the page.

The reason I chose the SPA design is that outside the tabs would be a chat system amongst other things running in the background that I don't want to resend to clients each time a redirect happens.

So my question is what is the best way to send the html, or is there a better way in general that still uses the SPA design?

Would the best way be to send the html in the router to the client, then use ajax to prevent a page refresh and add new tab html and remove old tab html after that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) with only one [route](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

This route could be called:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
}
```

Note that:

- This is a GET route
- It just sends the file contents with [sendFile](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

After that you can have many API routes to fetch the data for your tabs. I would recommend these routes to be like this:

```
app.post('/about',function(req, res) {
 res.json({ data: "your data here" });
}

app.post('/contact',function(req, res) {
 res.json({ data: "your data here" });
}
```

On these routes note that:

- These are POST routes
- Only a JSON is returned

Answer (score -1):

SPA means "single page app", and you will only have a single HTML shell that a JavaScript framework will then handle the "pages" and HTML after that

Comment: But you still need a server-side router for the correct status code -- like `404` and `403`. Otherwise, search engines will index those.

Comment: But in the client side javascript, should I use ajax's preventDefault() to stop a page redirect and then receive the data when a client selects a new tab? And in the server router should the new tab data be sent when it receives a GET or a POST from the client?

Comment: Yes. But it sounds like you should familiarize yourself with the general approach used by SPAs, and common frameworks before developing this 'from scratch': (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)